# python: number sequence

Tags: python, python-2.7

just wondering what's the easiest way to do this.. I have a file with the following contents:

```
01 04 
02 04 
04 04
```

I plan to edit my file to append **"missing** to the file, since 04 means there are 4 items, but number 3 is missing:

```
01 04 
02 04
#missing 
04 04
```

What is the easiest way to do this? I am pretty sure it's a simple fix, just that I am new to python and I keep trying very long-winded ways to implement this.

Hope to hear something from here, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4):

```
with open('path') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
        if int(line.split()[0]) == i:
            pass
        else:
            #put missing
```

i did't try this code. it's just concept.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry :) I get this error when I try out:                        Warning: 'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6
    with open(temp_file_path) as f:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

Using another file and then replace your file with it.

```
text = file('file_name','r').read() // read from file
list = '00 00' + [line for line in text]
new_list = []
l=len(list)
for i in xrange(1,l):
  new_list+=['missing' for i in range(int(list[i].split()[0])-int(list[i-1].split()[0])+1)]
  new_list.append(list[i])
```

then write new_list to a file then replace your file with this one

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
f = open('file.txt', 'r')
newfile = []
lines = f.readlines()
number = lines[0][-3:-1]
for i in range(int(number)):
    string = '0' + str(i+1) + ' ' + number
    if i + 1 != int(number):
        string += '\n'
    if string not in lines:
        newfile.append('missing\n')
    else:
        newfile.append(string)
f.close()
f = open('file.txt', 'w')
f.writelines(newfile)
f.close()
```

It worked when I tried with your example. It checks if a string is in the file, and writes `'missing'` if not.

Note: Not entirely sure if there is a mode for reading and writing (with truncating)